# How to update an element of an (arbitrarily) embedded list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I am trying to update an element in an arbitrarily embedded list of lists.

For example, a potential embedded list looks like:

```
lst = ['a', ['b', ['c', 'd']]]
```

And I want to update 'b' to the string "NEWVALUE". We can assume every element is unique, and, if it helps, every list is of length 2.

I have attempted to change the value of 'b' by obtaining the index of this element as a list of integers, using the solution provided in: [Index of an element in a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64299034/index-of-an-element-in-a-nested-list)

So, I have a variable containing the index of the value to be changed, as a list of integers.

```
embedded_index = [1,0]
```

Ideally, I would want to update the element doing something like:

```
lst[embedded_index] = "NEWVALUE"
```

so that the updated `lst` is `['a', ['NEWVALUE', ['c', 'd']]]`

But that obviously won't work Python doesn't access embedded indices using lists.

I have tried to update the value using the following code:

```
import copy
inner = copy.deepcopy(lst)
for i in embedded_index:
    inner = inner[i]

inner = "NEWVALUE"
```

But this does not update the original `lst`.

I do not necessarily need to use the `embedded_index` variable to update the value, this was the only way I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you `deepcopy` the original list. This means any changes made to `inner` won't show up in the original list. Don't do that.

Second, `inner = "NEWVALUE"` doesn't update the original list because at this point `inner` is a string, and you're simply reassigning the name to a different value. Instead, you want to drill down to the *last-but-one* element of `embedded_index` (which makes `inner` a list) and then use the last element to index into that list and set the value:

```
inner = lst # Do not deepcopy
for i in embedded_index[:-1]: # iterate up to second-last embedded_index
    inner = inner[i]

inner[embedded_index[-1]] = "NEWVALUE"
```

At the end of this code, `lst` becomes:

```
['a', ['NEWVALUE', ['c', 'd']]]
```

You might find it helpful to read [Python Names and Values by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)